# Correct way to call passport js function from react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook, passport.js

Hello I am new to react and Nodejs. Currently I am trying to make a login component in react which contains a button through which app can authenticate the user through Facebook. I am using passport.js for authentication. I am also using reflux for handling any api call to node server.

Below is the respective code for each

**actions.js**

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');

module.exports = Reflux.createActions([
    "facebookLogin"
]);
```

**store.js**

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var Actions = require('../actions');
var Api = require('../utils/api');

module.exports = Reflux.createStore({
    listenables: [Actions],

    facebookLogin: function(email) {
        Api.FBrequest(email)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('returned user for facebook from server : ' + response);
            }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

**api.js**

```
module.exports = {
    FBrequest: function() {
        return (
            fetch('/auth/facebook', {
                method: 'get'
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            })
        );
    }
};
```

**facebook.js**

```
// file at server for handling passport authentication calls
module.exports = function(app, passport){

    // call to facebook for authenticating user
    // in response to this call, facebook will reply in /auth/facebook/callback with the user object
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope:'email'}));

    // TODO return error on failure of login instead of navigating to the login route
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook',
        {failureRedirect: '/login'}), function(req, res){
            // user successfully authenticated by facebook
            // return the user object
            return req.user;
        });
};
```

When I click the fbLogin button on my app I get the following error

```
Fetch API cannot load https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=…3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=1807765906116990. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I want to know that is it correct approach to use fetch for directly sending the get to server for '/auth/facebook' and let the server handle the request and return with user object. If it is then where this is going wrong ? If it is not then what is the correct approach for achieving the same with react?

Comment: I do not see your passport configuration but my guess is you would have registered some domain (e.g. www.mysample.com) with facebook and your callback url is on the same domain. However since you testing this the request is coming from localhost which is not the registered domain. Try setting your hosts file (/etc/host on Mac) to point to your domain for the local loopback address: `code` 127.0.0.1 www.mysample.com

Comment: Did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this question like I did tonight - we solved this error by having the login button wrapped in an a href tag - which then takes the user to our authorization route. Once the user is authorized, facebook then returns the user to us. Then, every time our component mounts, we make sure the state has our logged in user mounted. If it doesn't we make a get request via axios to a route which passes back the user object, and we set our state appropriately.

Comment: _"Then, every time our component mounts, we make sure the state has our logged in user mounted. If it doesn't we make a get request via axios to a route which passes back the user object, and we set our state appropriately"_ Does it mean you save user object in back-end session to provide it for special route which passes back user object? I mean you save user object in session when user is authorized through facebook. Then you have special route for providing user object?